# How to get leJOS to run on macOS Sierra

Tags: nxt, lejos, mac

I am working with an eclipse plugin that requires it to run 32bit Java 6 on it and I do have Java 6 on my computer but when I run the program I get this error.

```
Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version.
Linking the file failed with exit status 1
```

The Java 6 I installed was from Apple's legacy Java 2015.
In the installation tutorial of leJOS it said that

> Note that even if you have a 64-bit system, leJOS will always chose to run java in 32 Bit mode by automatically passing the -d32 parameter to the java command whenever necessary.

If that is the case why doesn't my program run if I have Legacy Java 6 installed on my Mac? Can anyone get it to work on their mac on this version macOS?

Comment: I've gotten it to work on Sierra, minus Bluetooth support. There are a couple of hoops to jump through, that aren't made clear. I'll write up an answer later when I have time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to get leJOS working on macOS Sierra, minus Bluetooth support. [Bluetooth support is officially broken](https://lejos.sourceforge.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=3833) and has been for a while. [There also hasn't been a new release in years](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lejos/files/lejos-NXJ/), so a fix likely won't come. Otherwise it still works, if you jump through some hoops.

## Guide:

### 1. Fantom Driver:

First, you need to install the "Fantom driver". You can find on [the Mindstorms download page](https://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads).

Extract that ZIP, and you should have a installer package named `MAC legodriver.pkg`. Unfortunately, it may or may not install. Some people say it installs for them, but it doesn't install for me.

If it doesn't install, [someone has created a script](https://github.com/JrMasterModelBuilder/Mindstorms-Fantom-Drivers-Mac-Install) that can unpack the installer and get around the compatibility issues.

### 2. Legacy Java 6 with 32-bit support:

You need to install [Apple's legacy Java 6 package](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US) with 32-bit support. Sierra isn't listed as supported, but it still works.

This legacy version of Java probably won't become the default if you have a new version installed, but that's fine, we will configure leJOS to use this version later.

([Incidentally, there were some plans to make it support 64-bit Java](https://sourceforge.net/p/lejos/wiki-nxt/Route%20to%2064Bit%20on%20Windows%20and%20OS%20X/), but I wouldn't hold my breath.)

### 3. Download leJOS:

Download and extract leJOS for Mac [as instructed here](http://www.lejos.org/nxt/nxj/tutorial/Preliminaries/GettingStartedMac.htm#8).

### 4. Setup environment:

You need to setup some environment variables [as vaguely specified here](http://www.lejos.org/nxt/nxj/tutorial/Preliminaries/GettingStartedMac.htm#10). You will want to add something like the following to your `.bash_profile`, `.profile`, or other shell startup script, adjusting the `NXJ_HOME` to where you extracted leJOS.

```
# leJOS
export LEJOS_NXT_JAVA_HOME="/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home"
export NXJ_HOME="/Users/<USER>/<PATH_TO>/LeJOS/leJOS_NXJ_0.9.1beta-3"
export PATH="$PATH:$NXJ_HOME/bin"
```

(The `LEJOS_NXT_JAVA_HOME` variable is how you tell leJOS to use the legacy Java version.)

### 5. Profit:

Now when you open a new shell, the leJOS commands should work.

Comment: are you running eclipse Neon or an older version of Eclipse?

Comment: @ProgrammingCuber I've never used the Eclipse plugin. I'm afraid I don't know anything about it.

Comment: well if you could try it out and see if it works I would be interested :) just search the marketPlace and install it from there. Since you have the other things working it should be fine. Just upload the NXT firmware and then try to run a simple program and see what it outputs.

Comment: I did do everything  in your tutorial but I still have problems running it I still get the same error, I can't run it in eclipse.

Comment: @ProgrammingCuber If it's the 32-bit error, you might need to configure Eclipse to use a specific Java runtime or something. Not sure, I haven't used Eclipse in years.

Comment: It turns out that it need a lower version of eclipse :( I would have to downgrade from eclipse Oxygen down to eclipse luna from years ago .

Answer (score 2):

The one thing I needed to change to make the above solution work was this:

```
LEJOS_NXT_JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

I hope this can be of help to someone.

Wim